# How to perform action in jqGrid after adding new row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

is there an event in jqGrid to perform an action after adding new row?

I see in [jqGrid wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) that there is event afterInsertRow, but apparently it is triggered whenever jqGrid "inserts" rows to table while displaying the table.

Then what should I use when I want to do something after user "inserts" (saves) new row? Or, is there any variable that can let me "know" that new row was added?

Comment: You should describe more exactly which kind of "inserting" you use. For example you use form editing. The user click on the "Add" button and the data will be successfully saved on the server after the user clicked "Submit" button. You want to do some action (modify the server response) after receiving the response from the server that the data successfully added. Do you send back from the server the `id` of the new row or not?

Comment: Yes, user clicks on "add" button, fills in data for new row, clicks "submit" button, and new row in the table is created. I don't need to modify server response. In this particular case, I just need to select first row in the table, using setSelection method, but I need to prevent that behaviour if the new row was added. That is why I look for event for that.

Comment: And I have row id sent from server.

Comment: You still don't provide enough information. Do you use local grid or you save the data on the server? Do you sand back new row id from the server or not? If you returns id of the new row from the server you can use [reloadAfterSubmit: false](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) property. If you has default `reloadAfterSubmit: true` the grid will be just *reloaded* from the server. In any way to be able to select new row you should know the id of the selected row, but *the id will be generated typically by the server*.

Comment: Do you use paging of data on the server or you place all data on one page?

Comment: You can select or highlight the new row inside of `afterComplete` for example (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2946682/315935)), but it will work only in case of the usage of `reloadAfterSubmit: false` property. If you don't use paging of data it will be good enough, but to have all the data in the grid be correctly sorted or in case or data paging it will be needed to *reload* the full grid and select (or highlight) the new row *after reloading* inside of the `loadComplete`. Is it what you need?

Comment: Thanks, I will try with setting reloadAfterSubmit to false, that way he won't reload it so I won't have to worry what row he will select. Then I'll just manually reload the grid on other places.

Comment: Instead of that you can save the id of the new row in a variable (like `idToSelect`) inside of `afterComplete`. The grid will be reloaded. Inside of `loadcomplete` you can test whether `idToSelect` is set. In the case you can select the row and clear the `idToSelect`. I can provide you small code example if you need.

Comment: Yes, why not. I already tried with setting some variable, but it didn't do what I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is that to be able to select the row you need know the id of the new row. In the most situation the id will be generated by the database where you save the data on the server. So the first requirement to your server code is to return the id on the new row in the server response on the "add" operation.

For example your server code return the id of you row as the response on the "add" operation.

```
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {/*navGrid options*/}, {/*Edit optoins*/}, {
    /*Add options:*/
    reloadAfterSubmit: false,
    afterSubmit: function (response) {
        return [true, '', response.responseText];
    },
    addedrow: "last", // add new row at the end of grid
    afterComplete: function (response, postdata) {
        // this.gbox is the string like "#gbox_list"
        var gridId = this.gbox.substr(6);
        //if (postdata.oper === "add") {
        //    // highlight the new "added" row
        //    var row = $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(postdata.id));
        //    row.effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
        //}
        $('#' + gridId).jqGrid('setSelection', postdata.id);
    }
});
```

In the commented part of `afterComplete` I shown how you can use [jQuery UI highlight](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight) effect to highlight the new added row (see [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2946682/315935)). It can be alternative to the selection of the row. You can also use both selection and highlighting effects.

The option `reloadAfterSubmit: false` has at least two disadvantages.

1. If use use sorted data in the grid (`sortname` parameter of jqGrid is not empty) the rows of the grid will be *not correctly sorted* after the new row will be added as the first or as the last row in the grid.
2. If the grid has already maximum rows per page (defined by `rowNum` parameter), the adding of new row will follow to the grid with too many rows per page.

So you can do the following

```
var idToSelect;

$("#list").jqGrid({
    // ... all jqGrid options
    loadComplete: function () {
        if (idToSelect) {
            $(this).jqGrid('setSelection', idToSelect);
            //$("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(idToSelect)).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
            idToSelect = undefined;
        }
    }
}).jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {/*navGrid options*/}, {/*Edit optoins*/}, {
    /*Add options:*/
    afterSubmit: function (response) {
        // save the id of new row. If the format of the data returned from
        // the server is different you should change the next row
        // corresponds to the returned data. For example if the server returns
        // back JSON data in the form {"myId":"123"} you should use
        // $.parseJSON(response.responseText).myId
        // instead of response.responseText below
        idToSelect = response.responseText;
        return [true, '', response.responseText];
    }
});
```

In the case the new added row will be selected *after* the reloading of the grid.

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer. At last I did it with second solution.

Comment: @cincplug: You are welcome! I think the question will be interesting to other people, so +1 from me to your question.

Comment: finally my googling is stop because of your nice answer.Thank you very much.love it.

Comment: @Ashish4434: You are welcome! I like to know that my old answer is still helpful.