# save jqGrid Row to the server side collection with one line 'saveRow' method call?

Tags: jqgrid

THE PROBLEM:
Can I save a new jqGrid Row successfully added with 'addRowData' on jqGrid client side to the server side collection with one line 'saveRow' method call?

This is sort of a different version of a similar thread:
[How to perform action in jqGrid after adding new row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339463/how-to-perform-action-in-jqgrid-after-adding-new-row)

Although In my case it seems little different:

EXISTING:
I have a grid that talks to .ashx handler for insert update delete and reading.
(this works fine with inline editing etc.)

NEW FUNCTIONALITY:
I have just added Paste Button that pastes an array of text and converts it to rows:
long story short in the end two following lines of code finally add my split Data, row by row to my jqGrid:

```
var gridRow = { Id: rowId, Surname: rowSurname,  DateOfBirth: rowDateOfBirth, Salary: rowSalary, Postcode: rowPostcode };
            jQuery("#list").addRowData(rowId, gridRow);  //(**)
```

(as you see I KNOW my rowId, which I calculate searching through the existing data)

THE CATCH:
Above code adds new row on UI only and I wanted it to get it added to Server collection as well.

FAULTY:
After the line (**) I wanted to add it to server collection - simply using brand new call with saveRow passing URL. YET NOTHING HAPPENS

This is one variation of what I have already tried:

```
                                $("#list").jqGrid('saveRow', rowId, { //same rowId value used in 'addRowData' method above
                                    succesfunc: function (response) {
                                        return true;
                                    },
                                    url: "jqHandler.ashx",
                                    mtype: "POST",
                                    extraparam: gridRow // gridRow used in 'addRowData' method above
                                });
```

BOTTOM LINE:
Can I save a new jqGrid Row successfully added with 'addRowData' on jqGrid client side to the server side collection with one line 'saveRow' method call?

I would really appreciate some guidance.
Best Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

Sorted it out, may help someone, as it's simplistic:

All you need is to "Edit the row" so we just needed to add a Edit function call in the most simplistic way.

So the whole thing  looks like  this:

```
var gridRow = { Id: rowId, Surname: rowSurname,  DateOfBirth: rowDateOfBirth, Salary: rowSalary, Postcode: rowPostcode };
jQuery("#list").addRowData(rowId, gridRow);  

jQuery("#list").addRowData(rowId, gridRow);
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('editRow', rowId, { keys: true });

$("#list").jqGrid('saveRow', rowId, { //same rowId value used in 'addRowData' method above
                                    succesfunc: function (response) {
                                        return true;
                                    },
                                    url: "jqHandler.ashx",
                                    mtype: "POST",
                                    extraparam: gridRow // gridRow used in 'addRowData' method above
                                });
```

You may adjust so it uses same way of calling jQuery or jqGrid API. but it works...

Cheers